# Keep Mathematica from simplifying functions with a specified Head

Tags: expression-manipulation

I want to run `Simplify` and/or `Refine` on various expressions, but keep it from touching anything that contains a specific `Head`.

For example, I would like to `Refine` the following expression under the assumption `x>0` but not do anything with any part of the expression whose `Head` is `Log`:

```
expr = Sqrt[x^4] Log[x^2] + Log[x^4];
Refine[expr, x>0]
```

Instead of

```
(* 4 Log[x] + 2 x^2 Log[x] *)
```

I would like to see

```
(* x^2 Log[x^2] + Log[x^4] *)
```

Where the Logarithms remain unsimplified

Comment: `Simplify[expr, Assumptions -> {x > 0}, ExcludedForms -> {_Log}]` --- makes you wish `Refine` had the same option :)

Comment: ... maybe something like `Refine[expr /. Log -> log, x > 0] /. log -> Log`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `Simplify` there is the option `ExcludedForms`:

```
expr = Sqrt[x^4] Log[x^2] + Log[x^4];
Simplify[expr, Assumptions -> {x > 0}, ExcludedForms -> {_Log}]
(* x^2 Log[x^2] + Log[x^4] *)
```

For `Refine`, you can wrap the heads to be excluded with `Hold`:

```
Refine[expr /. Log -> Hold[Log], x > 0] // ReleaseHold
(*  x^2 Log[x^2] + Log[x^4] *)
```

or use `ReplaceAll` twice

```
Refine[expr /. Log -> "log", x > 0] /. "log" -> Log
(*  x^2 Log[x^2] + Log[x^4] *)
```

Answer (score 6):

With **V10** we can write

```
expr = Sqrt[x^4] Log[x^2] + Log[x^4] /. x_Log :> Inactivate[x];

Refine[expr, x > 0] // Activate
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Thanks to **Chip Hurst**'s comment the above should, of course, be written as

```
expr = Inactivate[Sqrt[x^4] Log[x^2] + Log[x^4], Log]
```

One of the advantages of `Inactivate` is that we can selectively `Activate`:

```
expr = Inactivate[Sqrt[x^4] Log[x^2] + Log[x^4] + Sin[Pi/2], Log | Sin];

Activate[Refine[expr, x > 0], Log]
```

[image]

```
Activate[%, Sin]
```

[image]

Another advantage is that - different from **kguler's** nice answer - the above examples don't have to distinguish `Simplify` from `Reduce`.

Comment: You could also do `expr = Inactivate[Sqrt[x^4] Log[x^2] + Log[x^4], Log]`, instead of pattern matching yourself.